# Javascript, how do I rotate my arrow div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have yet to create the dropdown portion but I want to be able to have the arrow, which I have create point down when clicking. Here is my code already. Everything I try when i select the div I receiving no action.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.circle').click(function() {
        $('#rotate').toggleClass('rotated');
    });
});
```

```css
.header{
  margin: -8px;
  height:75px;
  background-color: rgba(222,70,82,.7);
}
.circle{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border-radius:60px;
  border: solid 3px white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top:18px; 
}
.circle2{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  border-radius:60px;
  border: solid 2px white;
  position: absolute;
}

.arrow{
 content:'';
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  top:6px;
  left:4px;
  height:15px;
  width:15px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-top:4px solid white;
  border-right:4px solid white;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.rotated{
     transform:rotate(25deg); 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(25deg); 
    -moz-transform:rotate(25deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(25deg); 
}
```

```html
<header class = "header">

  <div class ="circle" >
    <div class = "circle2"
         </div>    
    
    <div class = "arrow"id="rotate"></div>
  </div></header>
```

`

Comment: You forgot to add jquery? (`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`)

Comment: ^^ Has to be it. Works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/rth94prt/

Comment: If you add jQuery as Kaiido points out, the arrow starts rotating when you click on it. A littlet adjustment to the transform property of rotated class and it will work: 'transform: rotate(135deg) translateX(-2px)'

Comment: I seriously cant believe I forgot to add that lol, thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Working after changing the transform to 135deg.

**Modified CSS**

```
.rotated{
     transform:rotate(135deg); 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(135deg); 
    -moz-transform:rotate(135deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(135deg); 
    margin-left: 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d08367ok/